# how to get data from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray as below.

```
products = (
        {
        fullName = Fahim;
        id = 1;
        photoName = "family-1.png";
    },
        {
        fullName = Nikhat;
        id = 2;
        photoName = "family-2.png";
    },
        {
        fullName = Naju;
        id = 3;
        photoName = "family-3.png";
    },
        {
        fullName = Dasd;
        id = 7;
        photoName = "family-7.png";
    },
        {
        fullName = Galib;
        id = 8;
        photoName = "family-8.png";
    }
)
```

Now what I want is pull data based on id.

e.x. if I say I need data for id 8, I should get fullName as Galib.

Any idea how to get this done? I am week in arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can replace value by %d as well.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d",YOUR_ID_VALUE];
```

For now you can use below,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == 8"];
NSArray *filter = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",filter);
```

Comment: I didn't accepted because SO time limit for accepting answers...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pull by id, use NSDictionary instead.

```
NSDictionary * products = @{
    @1: @{ @"fullName": @"Fahim", @"photoName":@"family-1.png"}, 
    @2: @{ @"fullName": @"Nikhat" @"photoName":@"family-2.png"}
};
```

That's still not the optimum way of doing it... hard to devise that without knowing your full requirements.

Comment: The items in the array _are_ dictionaries.

Comment: sample example code please...

Comment: @FahimParkar: How about if _you_ put some sample code up? This is super basic stuff.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, It doesn't matter what the items are. They should be stored in a dictionary and not array if they need to be searched by a key.

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the existing dictionary keys at another level. An array of dictionaries is a perfectly reasonable arrangement, and it can already be filtered or searched by _any_ of the keys in the dictionaries.

Comment: @FahimParkar, I've added the sample code.